# plt.imshow() circle with probability density inside

Tags: python, matplotlib, probability-density

I'm trying to use plt.imshow to create an image of a circle of a specified radius and image resolution. In the future this code will also be implemented with certain probability distributions inside the circle, but for now I'm just worried about a uniform one. This is what I have (uniform distribution with plt.imshow but not in the shape of a circle):

```
mu= 500
kappa= 1
array = np.random.uniform(mu,kappa, size=(2**n, 2**n))
plt.imshow(array, cmap='magma')
plt.show()
```

it creates a distribution like this:

[image]

and my goal is to have an image like this:

not my best art, but you get the point.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may use matplotlib's `Circle` patch (as described in [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/gallery/shapes_and_collections/dolphin.html#sphx-glr-gallery-shapes-and-collections-dolphin-py)):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, PathPatch
circle = Circle((500, 500), 500, facecolor='none',
             edgecolor=(0, 0.8, 0.8), linewidth=3, alpha=0.5)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
n=10
mu= 500
kappa= 1
array = np.random.uniform(mu,kappa, size=(2**n, 2**n))

ax.add_patch(circle)

im = plt.imshow(array, cmap='magma')

im.set_clip_path(circle)
plt.show()
```

This returns:

[image]